# Is there any method that can accelerate the python gredient calculation?

Tags: python, matrix, gradient, mathematical-optimization, jax

I am working on an algorithm which needs gradient information.
I tried ***numdifftools.Gradient***,this function works well,but the time cost is unsustainable.

Briefly,what Im doing is initializing a multi-dimensional(says d) vector ***t***,then use the ***t*** vector to parameterize a matrix ***A***,then the matrix along with other information gives a energy value,which is a scalar output.
I need the gradient (energy on t) element-wisely,so that i can update the t parameters and continue the loop.
My code looks like this:

```
def initialize(d):
    ......
    return t
def A(t):
    ......
    return A,result_2,result3...
def energy(t,A,para_2,para_3...)
    ......
    some matrix calculation including kron etc.
    ......
    return e
grad = numdifftools.Gradient(energy)(t) 
#this return the same shape of t 
#represents element-wise gradient w.r.t. the energy function.
t -= grad * learning_rate
```

**this works exactly what i want,however,when the dimension goes bigger,the gradient calculation may take several minutes in only 1 iteration,while I need to perform thousands of the iterations,**
I tried to use Google's JAX,and it seems that JAX only work when the output has just one scalar, while here I need matrix results.

Actually, u dont need to know what exactly I am doing,this is just a time cost optimization problem about gradient.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Please include a [MRE] not some pseudocode with vague explanations or hints to what you've tried with other libraries.

Comment: JAX's `grad` transform is designed for functions with a scalar output, but there are many other flavors of auto-differentiation available depending on what you want to compute (jacobian, elementwise grad, etc.) Unfortunately there's not enough information in your question to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cache decorator? It might help

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def my_function():
   """do things"""
```